# Discworld cookbook question

Tags: cookbook

How useful **is** the discworld cookbook to people in **our** world for cooking purposes? In other words do they use real world ingredients? Any notable successes?

I’m mostly curious & I don’t think it’s been covered on this stack before anyway

Comment: I'm torn between voting this up and voting to close as too broad/vague. Do you have specific concerns? Specific recipes you want to make and are unsure about? A link /some background might be useful too

Comment: Whether or not something is useful, and/or to what degree, is primarily opinion based, which is a justification for closing the question.    We try to deal with facts here, or at least testable hypotheses.  Is it possible to reformat your question to fit that criteria?  This is not the only cookbook based on fictional characters/worlds.  Perhaps a question about whether or not people have found successes or particular challenges using the recipes in such cookbooks? ...or a query about how a fictional ingredient might be substituted?

Comment: Hi Abraham, I am afraid your question is not the thing our site was built for. You can read it under https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. Specifically, it says "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." and that the questions should be "more than just mindless social fun". There is place for such fun in all our lives, but our site is not equipped to serve that function.

Comment: I’ve seen plenty of ‘fantasy’ cookbooks based on books / series (and own a few of them) and I’ve never seen one that wasn’t a real cookbook. Most of the ‘fake’ cookbooks Ive seen aren’t themed like that.  (I have a couple. But I’m not home. I think one is for mud pies). But in general, this sort of thing is probably better asked on the amazon page for the item, as it’s iffy that people on here have read specific cookbooks unless it’s something really famous (Fannie farmer, joy of cooking, Betty Crocker, the equivalent from other countries)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took a look at [the Amazon page for the book](https://www.amazon.ca/Nanny-Oggs-Cookbook-Terry-Pratchett/dp/0552146730/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) and using Look Inside discovered a number of relatively innocuous recipes. The ingredients are UK-ish (self-raising flour, for example) as are the names (Delight for a pudding and sauce combo, for example.) There is an old-fashioned tone to the dishes I spotted, which were exclusively desserts, though I didn't see all of them because See Inside doesn't show you much.

I didn't see a ton of actual recipes - there are pictures, and pages of text that I didn't read. If you're a Pratchett person (I am) it's delightful. If you're not, you will probably be quite confused. But I don't think any of the confusion will come from the actual recipes themselves.